# Applying Machine learning algorithms on .libsvm format datafiles

Tags: python, machine-learning, libsvm

I am currently working on .libsvm format datasets and I am unable to use different machine learning algorithms like kNN, SVM, Random forest on these datasets.

It is easy to apply them on .csv format but that method does not work on .libsvm file.

Please explain the method.

Comment: libsvm is a low level method , and has a simple estimator. You can convert your data to other format , and then try and build estimators on it using classical algorithms you mentioned like , kNN, SVM, Random forest.

Comment: @abunickabhi What are you trying to say? libsvm is a library and it's *simple estimator* is actually not that simple and it is an SVM. It's the lib used by sklearn doing (kernel-)SVMs.

Answer (score 1):

LIBSVM format is openly standardized and is arguably better to parse/use than csv's. The basic format can be seen [here](http://svmlight.joachims.org/).

But you don't need to do it yourself.

You can read those with [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) and it's [load_svmlight_file](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file.html):

> Load datasets in the svmlight / libsvm format into sparse CSR matrix

But make yourself familiar with sparse-matrices, although, when using sklearn, most stuff will work without you caring about dense vs. sparse.

I don't know much about the background / evolution of this format against the svmlight-format, but sklearn's docs say those are the same and i can support that by the experience ob being able to load all [libsvm datasets](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/) with the above function.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I have successfully loaded the dataset using sklearn but facing difficulty in applying Machine learning algorithms as the usual pandas function don't work on it.